# Getting "invalid assignment left-hand side"

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my JavaScript file I'm trying to load an external API JavaScript and calling function in callback. Its returning "invalid assignment left-hand side" on second line `window.loadApi  = function(callback) {`. Totally confuse because syntactically it is looking okay.

```
var apiUrl = window.location.protocol + "my url";
window.loadApi = function(callback) {
    if (window.$MY) {
        callback();
    } else {
        $.getScript(apiUrl, function() {
            $($MY.docReady);
            callback();
        });
    }
};

loadApi(function() {
    //my function
});
```

Comment: Has `window.loadApi` already been defined as a read-only property?

Comment: you need to correct this "window.loadApi  = function(callback)" what are you trying to do here

Comment: It looks like you're trying to to add an event handler for the `window.loadApi` event, but it doesn't look like you've instantiated `loadApi` as an actual event anywhere in your code. In fact, you seem to have it defined, instead, as a function.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine for me!